# PrimeNG AutoComplete: ForceSelection is set to true in autocomplete, still nothing is cleared on tab out or outside mouse click

Tags: typescript, primeng

I am using Prime NG autocomplete and my expectation is that if the input is not from the suggestions it should clear on tab  out and mouse click outside. I know there is a property called Forceselection and I am using it but it doesn't seem to work, Can any one point out if I am doing something wrong.

```
<p-autoComplete formControlName="trailerNumber" [suggestions]="bookCarrierModel.trailerList" field="label"
        [minLength]="3" placeholder="Enter Trailer #" (completeMethod)="searchTrailerList($event)"
        [forceSelection]="true" type="number"></p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: any one from primeNG team, can you please respond here?

Comment: It should work, you can check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-forceselection?file=src/app/app.component.html